# Adding Facebook account which is an admin of multiple FB pages through "Facebook OAUTH 2.0" Process?

Tags: facebook, oauth

I have developed an app which Posts and Reads the wall of the Page the user is admin of. I obtain Access Tokens through oAuth Process. This is working well when the user is admin of only one Page. But when he is the admin of multiple pages, I am not sure how to ask the user to choose a particular page during the oAuth process before/after approving the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way of doing this. I am binding all the pages for which the user is admin as a Radio Box List and asking him to choose which one he wants to connect with our app. And this way, the user feels he has the control over multiple pages he is admin of. I know this is a delayed reply though I implemented this long time back in my application but never late than before, I wanted to close this discussion by adding a solution of mine

Answer (score 1):

> But when he is the admin of multiple pages, I am not sure how to ask the user to choose a particular page during the oAuth process before/after approving the app.

You can't. The way Facebook have implemented `manage_pages` permission currently, the user can only give you access to **all** the pages they are admin of (or deny it completely) [1]

Once the user has given you that permission, you read `/userid/accounts`, and get a list of *all* their pages (and possibly apps, for a developer). You have to loop through those, to pick the access token for the specific page you're looking for.

---

[1] Which is rather stupid. As a user, I'd like to give an app access to a specific page only, not to all of them. Especially when you are admin for a lot of pages, you might not feel too comfortable having to give an app access to all of them, if that app is supposed to have access to only one.

Comment: That's exactly my point. I want the user to choose a page among the pages he is admin of and approve the app to post on that page only. But I guess right now there is no way we can do that.

Comment: I found a way of doing this. I am binding all the pages for which the user is admin as a Radio Box List and asking him to choose which one he wants to connect with our app. And this way, the user feels he has the control over multiple pages he is admin of. I know this is a delayed reply though I implemented this long time back in my application but never late than before, I wanted to close this discussion by adding a solution of mine